# Angular 2 #id and when element is not rendered

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form with three inputs:

```
<div>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input1 (change)="onTfChnage(input2)" type="text"/>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input2 (change)="onTfChnage(input3)" type="text"/>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input3 type="text"/>
</div>
```

At the beginning the three inputs are not rendered (using `*ngIf` with `false` condition) , then after 3 second i change `showInputs` to true to render them. When the inputs change event is fired i get an `undefined` for `nextInput` parameter

```
showInputs = false;
constructor(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.showInputs = true;
   },3000);
}
onTfChnage(nextInput){
  console.log(nextInput) // got undefined here
}
```

Comment: Plunker would be helpful.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: basically, i have some data i want to show in non-editable way and when the user click on edit, i should render all the inputs . on change event i should write some logic to test against, if a condition is true then focus the next input

Comment: Use `[hidden]` instead?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan good hint, this was what i a m looking for :) thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely *ngIf, you should be change to *ngHide when you're hiding value on a form that you might want to refer to again.  Using *ngIf doesn't hide something from the DOM, it actually removes it.  So you'll get undefined if you try to reference it.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Comment: the problem is I'm referencing them when they are in the DOM (*ngIf condition is true) and i got undefined this is somehow strange for me

Answer (score 0):

Use $event,

```
 <input #input1 (change)="onTfChnage($event)" type="text"/>
```

or you should be declaring the variable

```
input1 :ElementRef ;
input2:ElementRef;


  <input #input1 (change)="onTfChnage(input2)" type="text"/>
 <input #input2 (change)="onTfChnage(input1)" type="text"/>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GHImOSYrp2hIeqzje3N7?p=preview)**

Comment: i want the next input not the current input

Comment: did you see my demo?

Comment: yes and it is not what i want, basically i have 30 input in the same page so i gess declaring them in the component ts file will be painful :) thanks anyway

Comment: you can always use a array of objects then

Answer (score 0):

Pass in $event or $event.target and use js to get the next element. You could get fancier / more accurate with your selectors if need be, this is simplest form though:

```
<div>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input1 (change)="onTfChnage($event)" type="text"/>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input2 (change)="onTfChnage($event)" type="text"/>
 <input *ngIf = "showInputs" #input3 type="text"/>
</div>
```

Look for event.target.value in method:

```
showInputs = false;
constructor(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.showInputs = true;
   },3000);
}
onTfChnage(event){
  console.log(event.target.nextElementSibling.value) // next elements value
}
```

Comment: i want the next input not the current input

Comment: @Coyote - thanks for clarification, I updated the answer to get value of next element

Comment: i want a more generic solution, what if  the element after the first input was not the second input ? ( a div for example)  how can i refrence the second one?